# from JPA to XML file to Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have arranged for the following Camel route which marshals Entities from the DB to XML files:

```
<camelContext trace="true"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

<dataFormats>
    <jaxb contextPath="com.mycompany.model" id="jaxb-xml" />
</dataFormats>

    <route>

        <from uri="jpa:com.mycompany.model.User?consumeDelete=false&amp;consumer.namedQuery=User.findAll" />    
         <marshal ref="jaxb-xml"/>
        <to uri="file:/home/carla/fileout" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

It works but the problem is that the consumer keeps polling so adding unwanted additional XML copies in the fileout folder. What could be the most appropriate way to execute just once ?
Thanks!

Comment: You can stop the route after poll (Control bus EIP), if you like poll the data only once, or you can use idempotent consumer EIP, if you like continue polling user table.

Comment: Thanks, I'll opt for the first option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop your route using such processor:

```
public class StopRouteProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.getContext().stopRoute("jpaConsumer");
    }
}
```

Try to modify your bundle context like below:

```
<camelContext trace="true"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

<dataFormats>
    <jaxb contextPath="com.mycompany.model" id="jaxb-xml" />
</dataFormats>

    <route id="jpaConsumer">
        <from uri="jpa:com.mycompany.model.User?consumeDelete=false&amp;consumer.namedQuery=User.findAll" />    
        <marshal ref="jaxb-xml"/>
        <to uri="file:/home/carla/fileout" />
        <process ref="stopProcessor"/>
    </route>          
</camelContext>

<bean id="stopProcessor" class="com.mycompany.StopRouteProcessor"/>
```

Comment: Stopping a route so abruptly is maybe not the proper way to handle idempotence.

Comment: @Jonathan Schoreels  I agree, a wise way - to mark the consumed entities (using jdbc or sql сcomponents) or to bring them (they keys) in a idempotent repository.

Answer (score 0):

From [Camel doc](http://camel.apache.org/jpa.html)

> If you would rather perform some update on the entity to mark it as
>   processed (such as to exclude it from a future query) then you can
>   annotate a method with @Consumed which will be invoked on your entity
>   bean when the entity bean when it has been processed (and when routing
>   is done). From Camel 2.13 onwards you can use @PreConsumed which will
>   be invoked on your entity bean before it has been processed (before
>   routing).